# Pandas - Add incremental value if is null

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a merge between two dataframe using `Indicator=True` to check what values has on right and left side.

It's working pretty well.

Now, I need to add a column called `id` and this must be a number value - each row should have an unique value. If `indicator` shows side `left-only`, I need to get max value on column `id` and increment by 1 for each row present only on left side.

```
import pandas as pd

data_right = [{"id": 11, "name": "johnny", "department": "a"}]
data_left = [{"name": "robert", "department": "b"}, {"name": "climber", "department": "b"}]
df_right = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_right)
df_left = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_left)
df_merged = df_left.merge(df_right, on=["name", "department"], how="outer", indicator=True)
# df["id"] = ??
print(df_merged)
# how to get df["id"] = NaN and increment by 1 based on max value?
```

On above code, `id` from `robert` should be `12` and `climber` should be `13`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `cumsum` and `fillna`?

```
df_merged['id'] = df_merged['id'].fillna(
    df_merged['id'].max() + (df_merged['_merge'] == 'left_only').cumsum())

df_merged
  department     name    id      _merge
0          b   robert  12.0   left_only
1          b  climber  13.0   left_only
2          a   johnny  11.0  right_only
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using a custom function and `apply`.

```
start = df_merged['id'].max()
def setid(x):
    global start
    if np.isnan(x):
        start += 1
        return start
    else:
        return x

df_merged['id'] = df_merged['id'].apply(setid)
```

Here you simply increment when `df_merged['id']` is `NaN`, no need to check for the `_merge` column, so the `indicator=True` parameter when merging is not needed.